# changing device signature in avrdude

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, bootloader, programmer

I am trying to burn bootloaders to Atmega2560V and when I hit burn bootloaders it shows me this error

> avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9803
>   avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega2560 is 1E 98 01

I know this device should have 0x1e9801, But I don't know why it's showing me this error.

I tried my luck by starting threads at [AVRFREAKS](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/factory-reset-mega2560-and-mega2560v#comment-2241211) but no joy.

One of my friend told to try changing the device signature in the avrdude from 0x1e9801 to 0x1e9803 for a temporary try.

How can I do that.? please please please anyone help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should have, somewhere in your hard drive, a file named
avrdude.conf. My copy of the file has the following lines:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------
# ATmega2560
#------------------------------------------------------------

part
    id               = "m2560";
    desc             = "ATmega2560";
    signature        = 0x1e 0x98 0x01;
    ...
```

Try changing the line with `signature`. Alternatively, you could make a
new entry for your MCU like this:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------
# ATmega2560V
#------------------------------------------------------------
# Identical to  ATmega2560 but for the signature

part parent "m2560"
    id        = "m2560v";
    desc      = "ATmega2560V";
    signature = 0x1e 0x98 0x03;
```